# Interpolation function error: The quality of the underlying mesh is too low

Tags: warning-messages, interpolation, dataset, finite-element-method

Consider a dataset [BplustoPiXlight.dat](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PzqWI7XzfRmvYaFBvb1X73boE8hbPd-I) ([alternative link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2d14uq55u5cr3s3/BplustoPiXlight.dat?dl=0)).

I import it and try to interpolate:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
DataTable=Import["BplustoPiXlight.dat","Data"]
DataDistr=Interpolation[DataTable,InterpolationOrder->1]
```

However, Mathematica gives me the following error:

> Interpolation::femimq: The element mesh has insufficient quality of
>   -9.94174*10^-16. A quality estimate below 0. may be caused by a wrong ordering of element incidents or self-intersecting elements.
>
> Interpolation::fememtlq: The quality -9.94174*10^-16 of the underlying
>   mesh is too low. The quality needs to be larger than 0..

I tried first to rescale the data

```
DataDistr=Interpolation[{#[[1]], #[[2]], 10^20 #[[3]], 10^20 #[[4]]} & /@DataTable,InterpolationOrder->1]
```

However, it did not work (maybe since the "quality" is negative)... Could you please tell me how to resolve the issue?

Edit. It seems that I have found the solution. I just rescaled the first two rows by huge numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Just an extended comment.

If I look at the datapoints

```
p3D=DataTable[[All, {1, 2, 3}]];
ListPointPlot3D[p3D,PlotStyle -> PointSize[.001]]
(*sorry couldn't upload the plot *)
```

I see some slices of dence pointgrids, with strongly differing gridtopology.
This might be the reason why Interpolate doesn't succeed.

Meshing of these points

```
DelaunayMesh[p3D]
```

creates a MeshRegion without error but didn't show it!

Comment: The real question is if `ToElementMesh` gives messages (and it will) because that is what is used in `InterpolatingFunction`